# construction of the dojo.store.Memory in dojox.mobile.ComboBox

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojo

I have this in my App.html

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Pane">
                            <input id="codice_cliente" type="text" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ComboBox"
                                data-dojo-props='store:popola_codice_cliente()' placeHolder="Codice cliente" >
</div>
```

and this in my App.js

```
var codici_clienti;//build from adapter
function popola_codice_cliente(){



    return new dojo.store.Memory({ idProperty: "name", data:[{  name: codici_clienti[0].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[1].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[2].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[3].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[4].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[5].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[6].CDCLI  }, ] });
        return new dojo.store.Memory({ idProperty: "name", data:codici_clienti_data});
}
```

IT WORKS. But if I would like to dynamically build this array, the dojox.mobile.ComboBox doesn't work and it don't return anything.

```
function popola_codice_cliente(){
var codici_clienti_data;
if (result.invocationResult.resultSet.length>0) {
        codici_clienti=result.invocationResult.resultSet;
        codici_clienti_data="[ ";
        for (var i=0;i<codici_clienti.length;i++){
            codici_clienti_data+="{  name: codici_clienti["+i+"].CDCLI  }, ";

        }
        codici_clienti_data+="] ";

    }
return new dojo.store.Memory({ idProperty: "name", data:codici_clienti_data});
}
```

If I get the vAR codici_clienti_data from browser's console it returns:

```
"[ {  name: codici_clienti[0].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[1].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[2].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[3].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[4].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[5].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[6].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[7].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[8].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[9].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[10].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[11].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[12].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[13].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[14].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[15].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[16].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[17].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[18].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[19].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[20].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[21].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[22].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[23].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[24].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[25].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[26].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[27].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[28].CDCLI  }, {  name: codici_clienti[29].CDCLI  }, ] "
```

is there an alternative to populate the combobox(however, taking the data from a database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.eval()is solution!

```
if (result.invocationResult.resultSet.length>0) {
            var codici_clienti=result.invocationResult.resultSet;
            var mydata="[ ";
            for (var i=0;i<codici_clienti.length;i++){
                mydata+="{  name: codici_clienti["+i+"].CDCLI  }, ";

            }
            var lungh = mydata.length;
            mydata = mydata.substring(0,lungh-1); // tolgo l'ultimo carattere della stringa,ovvero la virgola

            mydata+="] ";

             codici_clienti_data = new Array();
            codici_clienti_data= eval (mydata);
```